# How to disable a cell/Column dynamically based on certain conditions in Extjs4?

Tags: extjs

I have extjs4 grid where I have Checkbox model and rowediting plugin. I want to disable a cell/column based on certain conditions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach listener `beforeselect` and do something like that:

```
grid.listeners = {
            beforeselect: function (grid, record, index, eOpts) {
                if(record.get('someParam') === "abc"){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };
```

And add row disabled style:

```
grid.viewConfig = {
            getRowClass: function (record, rowIndex) {
                if(record.get('someParam') === "abc"){
                    return 'selection-disabled';
                }
            }
        };
```

And in scss file:

```
.selection-disabled .x-selmodel-column {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @norbeq for the reply